# Other than physical form which characteristics define a woman?

Tags: aggregates

We know what a woman is. One can easily identify by her physical characteristics. Among the five aggregates form is only one of aspects which defines identity.
I want to know are there any other characteristics which define a women ?

Comment: I'm not sure that "form defines identity" is a very good summary of Buddhist doctrine.

Answer (score 4):

The Pali scriptures refer to the 'faculty of femininity' ('[itthindriya](https://suttacentral.net/define/itthindriya)'), as follows:

> Mendicants, there are these three faculties.What three? The faculties
>   of femininity (itthindriya),
>   masculinity (purisindriya) and life (jīvitindriya).
>
> [SN 48.22](https://suttacentral.net/sn48.22/en/sujato)

Thus, it appears the biological aggregate/faculty of form may possibly be one way to define a "woman" ([itthi](https://suttacentral.net/define/itthi)). However, it appears such a biological definition is not necessarily "identity" ("jati").

[SN 12.2](https://dhammadhatu.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/sn-12-2-paticcasamuppada-vibha%e1%b9%85ga-sutta/) defines "identity" ("jati") as follows:

> Yā tesaṃ tesaṃ sattānaṃ tamhi tamhi sattanikāye jāti sañjāti okkanti
>   abhinibbatti khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo āyatanānaṃ paṭilābho

Here, SN 12.2 (& also [MN 98](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/37490/does-the-buddha-deny-genetic-differences/37494#37494)) explains "identity" ("jati") is produced (abhinibbatti) from how both physical & mental aggregates are manifested & used (khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo) and from what sense objects are sought & taken possession of (āyatanānaṃ paṭilābho).

Therefore, the following suttas AN 6.52 & AN 7.51 below describe other characteristics which define a woman. In other words, AN 6.52 & AN 7.51, below, provide descriptions the manifestation & use of aggregates (*'faculties', 'gestures', 'manners', 'poise', 'desires', 'voice', 'charms', 'delight', 'excitement', 'attending outwardly', etc*) and the seeking/taking possession of sense objects (*such as 'a man', 'children', 'adornments', etc*) which may possibly define the category of beings (sattanikāye) called "women".

> Itthī kho, brāhmaṇa, purisādhippāyā alaṅkārūpavicārā puttādhiṭṭhānā
>   asapattībhinivesā issariyapariyosānā ti
>
> A man, O brahmin, is a woman’s aim, her quest is for adornments, her
>   mainstay is sons, her desire is to be without a co-wife and her ideal
>   is domination. ([Nyanaponika](https://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh208_Nyanaponika_Bodhi_Anguttara-Nikaya-Anthology--II.html#S28TheAimsofPeople))
>
> A man, brahmin, is the aim of women; their quest is for adornments;
>   sons are their support; they on intent on being without a rival; and
>   their final goal is authority. (Bodhi)
>
> Women have a man as their ambition. They’re preoccupied with
>   adornments. They’re dedicated to their children. They insist on being
>   without a co-wife. Their ultimate goal is authority. ([Sujato](https://suttacentral.net/an6.52/en/sujato))
>
> AN 6.52
>
> ---
>
> The Blessed One said: “A woman attends (manasi karoti) inwardly to her feminine
>   faculties (itthindriya), her feminine gestures, her feminine manners, feminine
>   poise, feminine desires, feminine voice, feminine charms. She is
>   excited by that, delighted by that. Being excited & delighted by that,
>   she attends outwardly to masculine faculties, masculine gestures,
>   masculine manners, masculine poise, masculine desires, masculine
>   voices, masculine charms. She is excited by that, delighted by that.
>   Being excited & delighted by that, she wants to be bonded to what is
>   outside her, wants whatever pleasure & happiness that arise based on
>   that bond. Delighting, caught up in her femininity, a woman goes into
>   bondage with reference to men. This is how a woman does not transcend (nātivattati) her femininity.
>
> [AN 7.51](https://suttacentral.net/an7.51/en/thanissaro)

The above said, an enlightened bhikkhuni (Buddhist nun) that does not manifest/use/possess aggregates & sense objects in the above described ways appears to not have the identity (jati) of "a woman", as follows:

> What does womanhood matter at all. When the mind is concentrated well.
>   When knowledge flows on steadily. As one sees correctly into Dhamma.
>
> One to whom it might occur, 'I'm a woman' or 'I'm a man' Or 'I'm
>   anything at all' — Is fit for Mara to address.
>
> SN
>   5.2

However, AN 7.51 does contain the phrase: "*This is how a woman transcends her femininity. Evaṃ kho, bhikkhave, itthī itthattaṃ ativattati*".

Therefore, it appears the 'faculty of femininity' ('[itthindriya](https://suttacentral.net/define/itthindriya)') or form aggregate may possibly generically define a "woman" however such "femininity" can be "transcended" ("ativattati") by not attending to it (na manasi karoti), by not manifesting it (na khandhānaṃ pātubhāvo) & by not identifying with it (anabhiratā).

> And how does one become unbound?
>
> Kathañca, bhikkhave, visaṃyogo hoti?
>
> A woman doesn’t focus on her own femininity:
>
> Itthī, bhikkhave, ajjhattaṃ itthindriyaṃ na manasi karoti—
>
> her feminine moves, feminine appearance, feminine ways, feminine
>   desires, feminine voice, and feminine adornment.
>
> itthikuttaṃ itthākappaṃ itthividhaṃ itthicchandaṃ itthissaraṃ
>   itthālaṅkāraṃ.
>
> She isn’t stimulated by this and takes no pleasure in it.
>
> Sā tattha na rajjati, sā tatra nābhiramati.
>
> So she doesn’t focus on the masculinity of others:
>
> Sā tattha arattā tatra anabhiratā bahiddhā purisindriyaṃ na manasi
>   karoti—
>
> masculine moves, masculine appearance, masculine ways, masculine
>   desires, masculine voice, and masculine adornment.
>
> purisakuttaṃ purisākappaṃ purisavidhaṃ purisacchandaṃ purisassaraṃ
>   purisālaṅkāraṃ.
>
> She isn’t stimulated by this and takes no pleasure in it.
>
> Sā tattha na rajjati, tatra nābhiramati.
>
> So she doesn’t desire to bond with another.
>
> Sā tattha arattā tatra anabhiratā bahiddhā saṃyogaṃ nākaṅkhati.
>
> Nor does she desire the pleasure and happiness that comes from such a
>   bond.
>
> Yañcassā saṃyogapaccayā uppajjati sukhaṃ somanassaṃ tañca nākaṅkhati.
>
> Sentient beings who are not attached to their femininity are not bound
>   to men.
>
> Itthatte, bhikkhave, anabhiratā sattā purisesu visaṃyogaṃ gatā.
>
> This is how a woman transcends her femininity.
>
> Evaṃ kho, bhikkhave, itthī itthattaṃ ativattati.
>
> [AN 7.51](https://suttacentral.net/an7.51/en/sujato)

Answer (score 1):

In the Sabbasava Sutta, Buddha described questions regarding identity as "inappropriate attention":

> When a monk attends inappropriately, unarisen fermentations arise, and arisen fermentations increase.
>
> ...
>
> "This is how he attends inappropriately: 'Was I in the past? Was I not in the past? What was I in the past? How was I in the past? Having been what, what was I in the past? Shall I be in the future? Shall I not be in the future? What shall I be in the future? How shall I be in the future? Having been what, what shall I be in the future?' Or else he is inwardly perplexed about the immediate present: 'Am I? Am I not? What am I? How am I? Where has this being come from? Where is it bound?'
>
> "As he attends inappropriately in this way, one of six kinds of view arises in him: The view I have a self arises in him as true & established, or the view I have no self... or the view It is precisely by means of self that I perceive self... or the view It is precisely by means of self that I perceive not-self... or the view It is precisely by means of not-self that I perceive self arises in him as true & established, or else he has a view like this: This very self of mine — the knower that is sensitive here & there to the ripening of good & bad actions — is the self of mine that is constant, everlasting, eternal, not subject to change, and will stay just as it is for eternity. This is called a thicket of views, a wilderness of views, a contortion of views, a writhing of views, a fetter of views. Bound by a fetter of views, the uninstructed run-of-the-mill person is not freed from birth, aging, & death, from sorrow, lamentation, pain, distress, & despair. He is not freed, I tell you, from suffering & stress.

https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.002.than.html